# Select all checkoxes if selected top one laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

in my user.js file i have wrote following method as

**js**

```
$('.group-selector-campaign').click(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.group-campaign-').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.group-campaign-').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

**View**

```
 <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes">
                     </label>
                            </th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Created at</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
```

Its my header and i want if header checkbox selected all below checkbox will also b select automatically.
Below for all other table fields i use this for 2nd line and so on

```
<label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1">
                                   </label>
```

its not working dont know why.
    Ist of all is my function correct if yes then how and where add **group-selector-campaign** class to work properly

Comment: First you should check your all selectors you have used as i don't see `.group-selector-campaign` and `group-campaign-` in your html

Comment: can you check 
$('.group-campaign-').attr('checked', true);
$('.group-campaign-').attr('checked', false);

Comment: why is this tagged laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.

```
----- jQuery Syntax --------

$('.top-selector').click(function () {

    var this_element = $(this);

    var check = false;
    if(this_element.is(":checked")) {
        check = true;
    }

    // var campaign-checkboxes = 
    this_element.find('select.group-selector-campaign').each(function (i) {
        if(check) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        }
    })

});

----- HTML Syntax --------

<select type="checkbox" class="top-selector" value="">
<div class="campaign-checkboxes">
    <select type="checkbox" class="group-selector-campaign" value="">
    <select type="checkbox" class="group-selector-campaign" value="">
    <select type="checkbox" class="group-selector-campaign" value="">
    <select type="checkbox" class="group-selector-campaign" value="">
</div>
```

Hope this helps.